# Set an ant option with -D

Tags: ant

Suppose I have this ant task which takes a string and prints it.

```
public class MyTask extends Task
{
    private String msg;

    // method executing the task
    public void execute() throws BuildException
    {
            System.out.println(msg);
    }

    public void setMessage (String msg)
    {
            this.msg = msg;
    }
}
```

How should I write my buildfile to pass the string argument  to it?

(Say I'd like do something like  `ant mytask -Dmessage=print_this_message`)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the task within your build file and pass the property value as an attribute

```
<taskdef ....

<mytask message="${message}"/>
```

## update

To set default value on the task's strings just initialise the message private variable

```
public class MyTask extends Task
{
    private String msg = "hello world";

    public void execute() throws BuildException
    {
            System.out.println(msg);
    }

    public void setMessage (String msg)
    {
            this.msg = msg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. But what if I want the explicitly specify what the default value would be if someone doesn't specify it?

Comment: @user1064918. The default value of the message can be set within the custom ANT task. I've updated the answer